# timeout on running protractor tutorial with internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, protractor

I use protractor 3.30 with ie driver 2.52.0 and ie 11.

I want to follow the [protractor tutorial](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/tutorial) with internet explorer:

My protractor config file is:

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['performance_test.js'],
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'internet explorer',
        'ignoreZoomSetting': true,
        'platform': 'ANY',
        'version': '11'
    }
};
```

My test file is from the tutorial:

```
describe('angularjs homepage todo list', function() {
    it('should add a todo', function() {
        browser.get('https://angularjs.org');

        element(by.model('todoList.todoText')).sendKeys('write first protractor test');
        element(by.css('[value="add"]')).click();

        var todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'));
        expect(todoList.count()).toEqual(3);
        expect(todoList.get(2).getText()).toEqual('write first protractor test');

        // You wrote your first test, cross it off the list
        todoList.get(2).element(by.css('input')).click();
        var completedAmount = element.all(by.css('.done-true'));
        expect(completedAmount.count()).toEqual(2);
    });
});
```

When I run the line:

> protractor conf.js

I get the following error:

> [14:16:18] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
>
> [14:16:18] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
>   Started
>
> A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
>
> F
>
> Failures:
>
> 1) angularjs homepage todo list should add a todo
>
> Message:
>       Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
>     Stack:
>       Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
>
> at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)
>
> 1 spec, 1 failure
>
> Finished in 30.027 seconds
>
> [14:18:46] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
>
> [14:18:46] I/launcher - internet explorer11 #01 failed 1 test(s)
>
> [14:18:46] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
>
> [14:18:46] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1

When I look at the selenium log i see as last command

```
14:16:29.347 INFO - Done: [execute script: try { return (function (model, using, rootSelector) {
  var root = document.querySelector(rootSelector || 'body');
  using = using || document;

  if (angular.getTestability) {
    return angular.getTestability(root).
        findModels(using, model, true);
  }
  var prefixes = ['ng-', 'ng_', 'data-ng-', 'x-ng-', 'ng\\:'];
  for (var p = 0; p < prefixes.length; ++p) {
    var selector = '[' + prefixes[p] + 'model="' + model + '"]';
    var elements = using.querySelectorAll(selector);
    if (elements.length) {
      return elements;
    }
  }
}).apply(this, arguments); }
catch(e) { throw (e instanceof Error) ? e : new Error(e); }, [todoList.todoText, null, body]]
14:16:29.357 INFO - Executing: [send keys: 0 [org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement@bdfbd98 -> unknown locator], [write first protractor test]])
14:16:53.470 INFO - Executing: [delete session: d575f16c-51f0-4b0e-9531-1bcd00d3b7e2])
14:18:45.352 INFO - Done: [send keys: 0 [org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement@bdfbd98 -> unknown locator], [write first protractor test]]
14:18:46.356 INFO - Done: [delete session: d575f16c-51f0-4b0e-9531-1bcd00d3b7e2]
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I had identical problem I think. Try to add this to your config:

```
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 2500000,
},
```